# Programmatically like a facebook fan page in Facebook android SDK

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am working in an android application where I use the facebook android sdk to login to the application.I get the access token from the facebook sdk when user logged in to the application through facebook sdk.

So is it possible to like a page in facebook pragmatically having access token of a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To like a post on facebook, I use this part of code to create the request.

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), pageid + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

    }
});
```

Where I already logged in to Facebook, so I can just call the Session.getActiveSession().

Then I execute the request with:

```
Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
```

You should run this in an Asynctask, since you are not allowed to do network stuff on your main thread.

Comment: I used these imports: 
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;

Did you add the facebook sdk as a Library project in your Android project properties?

Comment: not work, response contain: `{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) App does not have permission to make this call}, isFromCache:false}`

Comment: Please mark this answer as unanswered, because it is not allowed as mentioned bellow.

Comment: I think I read it wrong, can't really remember it since it's more than a year ago.. Would love to delete my answer, but I can't since it's accepted as answer :(

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/likes .... this seems relevant to the discussion for anyone else. talking about liking an OBJECT tho.

Answer (score 19):

It's not possible to like a **page** programmatically, only comments and posts. I don't know why you marked the previous answer as correct, it does not work and it's quite misleading.